# Obtener Fecha desde la Base de Datos

Tags: java, mysql

Necesito obtener la fecha (en particular el año) desde la base de datos para integrarlo a Java

```
    String now = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ), '%Y' )";
          try {
        java.sql.Statement sp=cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet RS = sp.executeQuery(now);
        while(RS.next()){
            ahora = RS.getInt("Now");  
            System.out.println(ahora);
        }
```

sin embargo el "Now" no lo reconoce dentro de la tabla... (ya que no existe) como puedo obtener ese dato para implementarlo a la variable "ahora"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intenta darle un alias a la columna asi:

```
String now = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ), '%Y' ) AS ahora";
      try {
    java.sql.Statement sp=cn.createStatement();
    ResultSet RS = sp.executeQuery(now);
    while(RS.next()){
        ahora = RS.getInt("ahora");  
        System.out.println(ahora);
    }
```

Comment: gracias!! se me fue el Alias ! u.u

Comment: Solo cambia la `Y` por `y`